# datetime imports not working (python with Django)

Tags: python-2.7, django-views

This is weird, but datetime seems not to be working

I am trying to follow the django tutorial, (chapter 3, http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter03.html). But the code further below throws a syntax error:
undefined variable from import: datetime

It does not like the statement "now = datetime.datetime.now()"

---

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime

def current_datetime(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    html = "<html><body>It is now %s.</body></html>" % now
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

---